# How to group results by a date/time period in MySQL while still using an index?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, query-optimization

In MySQL, you can create an index to be used in a query to prevent full tables scans. Only one index can be used.

Furthermore, in order to use the index, the field(s) indexed cannot be run through a function (i.e. `DATE(), MONTH(), YEAR()`) because then the query optimizer won't know what the result will be so can't use the index and will fall back to a full (or partial) table scan instead.

Assuming you wanted to run a report that grouped entries by day/month/quarter/year (`GROUP BY date(created_at)`) how could you designed a query that would do this while still using an index?

Example Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `datesort` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `c_v` (`created_at`,`value`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

-- Problem Query
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*), `value`, created_at
FROM datesort
WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY date(created_at), value;

-- Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

vs

EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*), `value`, created_at
FROM datesort
WHERE created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY created_at, value;

-- Using where; Using index 
-- (notice no DATE() in GROUP BY)
```

Notice the first query has to result to a partial table scan (`Using temporary; Using filesort`) because it can't use the `c_v` index because of the `DATE(created_at)`.

The second query doesn't sort by date (it sorts by seconds) but can use the index alone without resulting to reading the record data.

Since grouping by time periods is pretty common with reports, how can I group records by day/month/quarter/year using just the index?

Comment: ? But it is using an index

Comment: @Strawberry, you're correct, it does use the index for part of the query. I updated the language to be clearer.

Comment: You could add extra columns to the table in different date formats that you might need to query on. i.e. store datetime `2020-05-13 16:40:00`, but then also split out year `2020`, month `05`, day `13`, date `2020-05-13` in separate columns to query on. So if you know you'll be querying your data only on datetime or date(), then you just need the date stored in those 2 formats. But if you don't know which formats you might need, then you could add extra columns additionally for `hour`, `minute`, `second` etc. This is the cost of space vs time :)

Comment: I don't trust MySQL to use indexes for `group by`.  It seems to work only under special circumstances (unless the optimizer has gotten much better recently).

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones as long as you have the space, that would work as long as you don't need to take timezones into account when grouping. (i.e. what is 'Tuesday' in Hong Kong vs New York?)

Comment: @Xeoncross well that case applied if you're storing a datetime anyway. To get around that you could save everything as a unix timestamp instead, or save the timezone in yet another column (though then your queries get pretty complex to try to account for all datetimes in all timezones).

Comment: Adding onto WONDED's suggestion:  Make the columns "generated" (and indexed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending on helpful comments by [WOUNDEDStevenJones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1499877/woundedstevenjones) and [Rick James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766831/rick-james): you could create a generated column that stores the date part of each record (without the time component) and index it.

```
alter table datesort
    add column date_created_at date
    generated always as (date(created_at)) stored
;

create index myidx on datesort(date_created_at, value);
```

Now you can try your query again. To get the full benefit of the index, you would ideally need to change the `where` clause so it uses the generated date column rather than the original datetime column (hopefully, this still fits your use case):

```
select count(*) cnt, value,  date_created_at
from datesort
where date_created_at > current_date - interval 1 day
group by date_created_at, value;
```

This produces the expected `explain`:

```
id | select_type | table    | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra                   
-: | :---------- | :------- | :--------- | :---- | :------------ | :---- | :------ | :--- | ---: | -------: | :-----------------------
 1 | SIMPLE      | datesort | null       | index | myidx         | myidx | 8       | null |    1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8143fa7a0b3aad206b8e3faef31cced1)**

Comment: Thank you for the extend example, unfortunately this comes with a couple of issues: grouping by certain time ranges (days, weeks, months, quarters, annual) each require their own index. Every additional index adds storage cost and insert time. Furthermore, you loose the ability to use timezone information in calculations as the generated column is generated in whatever timezone is currently set. Still, this might be the best answer possible.

Comment: @Xeoncross: yes, if you want to handle other granularities (month, quarter, ...), then you need more generated columns. I guess this is the price to pay for optimization...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to answers others have posted, if adding new columns is not always an option, particularly in scenario when you are having to do it on many tables and performance optimization is the only reason.

One option is to upgrade to the latest version - MySQL 8.0.13 supports function based indexs. This allows indexing of values in a column which are not stored in a column. Check [Functional Indexes in MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts)

Eg of how to create it:

```
CREATE TABLE test (c1 Timestamp, c2 INT, INDEX func_index ((Date(col1))));
```

In earlier versions you could also solve this issue, in addition to adding columns, by changing the data type of Date_Created to `VARCHAR` and then creating a index on the column prefix - in this care just the first 10 characters ( just the date part ).

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  col1 VARCHAR(10),
  col2 VARCHAR(30),
  INDEX idx (col2(10))  /* this gives you just the date portion */
);
```

Comment: The index on a string prefix is a creative solution, unfortunately, it would use more space than two date fields so not practical for this (`x2 timestamp as an int32 + int32` vs `80bit VARCHAR(10)`)